# GridSearchCV scoring and grid_scores_

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to understand how to obtain the values of the scorer for the [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html). The example code below sets up a small pipeline on text data.

Then it sets up a grid search over different ngrams.

The scoring is done through the f1 measure:

```
#setup the pipeline
tfidf_vec = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', min_df=0.05, max_df=0.95)
linearsvc = LinearSVC()
clf = Pipeline([('tfidf_vec', tfidf_vec), ('linearsvc', linearsvc)])

# setup the grid search
parameters = {'tfidf_vec__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2)]}
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(clf, parameters, n_jobs=-1, scoring='f1')
gs_clf = gs_clf.fit(docs_train, y_train)
```

Now I can print the scores with:

print gs_clf.grid_scores_

```
[mean: 0.81548, std: 0.01324, params: {'tfidf_vec__ngram_range': (1, 1)},
 mean: 0.82143, std: 0.00538, params: {'tfidf_vec__ngram_range': (1, 2)}]
```

print gs_clf.grid_scores_[0].cv_validation_scores

```
array([ 0.83234714,  0.8       ,  0.81409002])
```

It is not clear to me from the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html):

1. Is gs_clf.grid_scores_[0].cv_validation_scores an array with the scores defined through the scoring parameter, per fold (in this case, the f1 measures per fold) ? If not, what is it then?
2. If I instead choose another [metric](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html), such as scoring='f1_micro', each array in gs_clf.grid_scores_[i].cv_validation_scores will contain the f1_micro metric for the folds for a particular grid search parameter selection?

Comment: Yes you're understanding correctly

Answer (score 6):

I wrote the following function to convert a `grid_scores_` object to a `pandas.DataFrame`. Hopefully, the dataframe view will help clear up your confusion, as it's a more intuitive format:

```
def grid_scores_to_df(grid_scores):
    """
    Convert a sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.grid_scores_ attribute to a tidy
    pandas DataFrame where each row is a hyperparameter-fold combinatination.
    """
    rows = list()
    for grid_score in grid_scores:
        for fold, score in enumerate(grid_score.cv_validation_scores):
            row = grid_score.parameters.copy()
            row['fold'] = fold
            row['score'] = score
            rows.append(row)
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    return df
```

You'll have to have the following import for this to work: `import pandas as pd`.